# Migrate PropertyData to a new PropertyType

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We have an existing `PropertyType` called `IsPublic` which uses a `Umbraco.TrueFalse` property editor.

Requirements have changed and this value now needs to be represented by multiple checkboxes that are driven from an Enum with the Values `Public`, `Group1`, `Group2`.

This all works as expected but with 10's of Thousands of documents we want to save our content editors from manually populating them all.

Saving a document in Umbraco, I can see that it creates an entry in the table `cmsPropertyData` with the value `[    "Public",    "Group1",    "Group2"  ]` in the `dataNvarchar` column.

I've written a script to insert a row into this table based on the value of the original `IsPublic` flag.

However following running this, when opening a document in Umbraco the changes aren't displayed.

The script used to update is

```
DECLARE @HasPublicFlag NVARCHAR(50) = '[    "Public",    "Group1",    "Group2"  ]'
DECLARE @NoPublicFlag NVARCHAR(50) = '[    "Group1",    "Group2"  ]'

DECLARE @feature INT = (SELECT nodeId FROM cmsContentType WHERE Alias = 'Feature')

--Existing IsPublic flag
DECLARE @featureIsPublic INT = (SELECT id FROM cmsPropertyType WHERE Alias = 'IsPublic' AND contentTypeId = @feature)

--New PropertyType
DECLARE @featureRoleRestriction INT = (SELECT id FROM cmsPropertyType WHERE Alias = 'documentRoleRestriction' AND contentTypeId = @page)

--Get feature document versions that are either newest version or published
;WITH FeatureDocumentsToUpdate AS
(
    SELECT d.*, pd.dataInt
    FROM cmsDocument d 
    JOIN cmsPropertyData pd ON pd.versionId = d.versionId
    LEFT JOIN cmsPropertyData pd2 ON pd2.versionId = d.versionId AND pd2.propertytypeid = @featureRoleRestriction
    WHERE (d.newest = 1 OR d.Published = 1) AND pd.propertytypeid = @featureIsPublic AND pd2.id IS NULL
)

--INSERT INTO cmsPropertyData based on value of existing flag
INSERT INTO cmsPropertyData(contentNodeId, versionId, propertytypeid, dataNvarchar)
SELECT s.nodeId, versionId, @featureRoleRestriction, 
    CASE WHEN s.dataInt = 0 THEN @NoPublicFlag ELSE @HasPublicFlag END AS NewValue
FROM FeatureDocumentsToUpdate s
```

Is there another table(s) that will need updating or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you need to republish all of the affected pages for the caches etc to update and populate with the new values properly.

With 10,000 plus documents, doing a full republish of everything might be quite slow.

You could also try and update the XML for each page in the cmsContentXml table to have the correct values, and then rebuild the Examine indexes for the site, which should do the trick and be a bit quicker. This is because the contents this table is used to rebuild the indexes to save on speed.

Another option would be to write an API Controller task that you can run once and then remove to update all of the values using the Umbraco Services, but again, that'll be quite slow I think on the volume of pages you're talking about.